# Matlab fails to validate parallel environment

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

When I run **Parallel** >> **Manage Congifurations...**, Matlab fails to pass the **Distributed Job**, the **Parallel Job** and the **Matlabpool** tests. My system has a double core: Intel Core i5 CPU M520 @ 2.40GHz 2.40GHZ, 2GB RAM, Win7 64bit, Matlab R2011b. After the failed validation, I get the following output:

> Validation Details
>
> Configuration: "local" Type: local
>
> -------------------------------------- Stage: Find Resource
>
> Status: Passed Description:  Validation passed
>
> Command Line Output: (none)
>
> ---
>
> -------------------------------------- Stage: Distributed Job
>
> Status: Failed Description:  The given stage reached the default or
>   user-specified timeout.
>
> Command Line Output: (none)
>
> Error Report: (none)
>
> Debug Log: LOG FILE OUTPUT:
>
> ---
>
> -------------------------------------- Stage: Parallel Job
>
> Status: Failed Description:  The given stage reached the default or
>   user-specified timeout.
>
> Command Line Output: (none)
>
> Error Report: (none)
>
> Debug Log: LOG FILE OUTPUT:
>
> ---
>
> -------------------------------------- Stage: Matlabpool
>
> Status: Failed Description:  A MATLAB pool is already open and might
>   interfere with further testing. To avoid this, before the next test
>   run try executing "matlabpool close".
>
> Command Line Output: (none)
>
> Error Report: (none)
>
> Debug Log: (none)
>
> ---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty much what I get if I've called `matlabpool` prior to running the validation checks.  You did pay attention to the advice given in the Status report from the Matlabpool stage didn't you, about closing an open matlabpool ?

Comment: Ok, that helped. What do you mean by "Matlabpool stage"? Obviously I didn't pay attention.

Comment: The status report produced by the validation test consists of 4 test 'stages' as your question (above) shows.